# PrimeFaces, sort p:column based on a property of a property

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I'm working on a JSF 2.1 project using PrimeFaces, Spring and Hibernate.

I have an entity called Provinces related to an entity called Region by a JoinColumn:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROVINCE")
public class Province  {

    /* ... */        
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_REGION",nullable=false)
public Region getRegion() {
    return region;
}

public void setRegion(Region region) {
    this.region = region;
}

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable=false)
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "REGION")
public class Region  {

    /* ... */        
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "region")
public List<Province> getProvince() {
    return province;
}

public void setProvince(List<Province> province) {
    this.province = province;
}

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable=false)
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

}
```

On a JSF page I have a `p:dataTable` that shows a listing of the Provinces. Among the others I have a column showing the name of the region that the province belongs to.
Something like:

```
        <p:dataTable id="provincesDatatable"
        value="#{provinceMB.lazyProvinceViewModel}" 
        var="province"
        paginator="true" rows="15" lazy="true"
        emptyMessage="Nothing to see here, move along"
        paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
        selection="#{admProvinceMB.selectedProvince}" selectionMode="single"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

        <p:column headerText="Province Name"
            sortBy="#{province.description}">
            <h:outputText value="#{province.description}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Region Name"
            sortBy="#{province.region}">
            <h:outputText value="#{province.region.description}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

(I'm omitting the backing bean and the LazyDataModel implementation as I think they aren't related to the problem, but if needed I can show them).
This works fine, with the exception of sorting by region.

The example above will order by region id, while I'd like to sort by region description, something like the following, which doesn't work.

```
<p:column headerText="Region Name"
    sortBy="#{province.region.description}">
    <h:outputText value="#{province.region.description}" />
</p:column>
```

Trying this will give me the error  org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: region.description of: my.package.entity.Province

The only solution I could come up with is adding a transient field to `Province` called `regionDescription` which returns the description of the associated region, but it is a very ugly hack.
Is there a better way to obtain this result ?

Edit: the problem was elsewhere. here's the relevant code from the LazyDataModel

```
public List<Province> findLazyProvince(int startingAt, int maxPerPage,
        String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters)
{
    Criteria crit = buildCriteria(filters);

    if (sortField != null && !sortField.isEmpty()) {
        if (sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)) {
            crit = crit.addOrder(Order.asc(sortField));
        } else {
            crit = crit.addOrder(Order.desc(sortField));
        }
    }
    crit = crit.setFirstResult(startingAt).setMaxResults(maxPerPage);
    return crit.list();
}
```

Comment: Since you are using LazyDataModel, your code should take care of sorting.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I mean, that's what I'm doing but also that's where the problem lies; I'll update the question accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was a silly mistake on my part: the sort field (in my case "region.description") is passed unchanged as a string to the LazyDataModel, so it is my duty to handle it appropriately in the code by adding an alias.

So the code above should become something like

```
public List<Province> findLazyProvince(int startingAt, int maxPerPage,
    String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters)
{
    Criteria crit = buildCriteria(filters);

    if (sortField != null && sortField.equals("region.description")) {
        crit.createAlias("region", "region");
    }
    if (sortField != null && !sortField.isEmpty()) {
        if (sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)) {
            crit = crit.addOrder(Order.asc(sortField));
        } else {
            crit = crit.addOrder(Order.desc(sortField));
        }
    }
    crit = crit.setFirstResult(startingAt).setMaxResults(maxPerPage);
    return crit.list();
}
```